# How to implement stacks in Tcl without using lists?

Tags: data-structures, stack, tcl

I know implementing stacks and queues with lists is very easy. But how would I implement a stack without using lists and list-manipulation functions such as `lappend` and `lindex`?

Actuallt I am using Tcl in Synopsys, so all the item in a stack are a part of circuit, like cells, ports, nets... which are collections in synopsys and cannot be processed directly through list function.

Comment: Does it have to be efficient? You could use strings, or arrays and a integer counter for the current index. Or namespaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *right* data structure is a list. However, you can make one by using an array. Here are the classic operations:

- `init` to set an empty stack up
- `push` to add a value to the stack
- `size` to report the number of elements on the stack
- `top` to peek the top-most value on the stack
- `pop` to remove and return the top-most value on the stack

```
proc init {stackVar} {
    upvar 1 $stackVar stk
    unset -nocomplain stk
    set stk(top) -1
}
proc push {stackVar value} {
    upvar 1 $stackVar stk
    set stk([incr stk(top)]) $value
    return
}
proc size {stackVar} {
    upvar 1 $stackVar stk
    return [expr {$stk(top) + 1}]
}
proc top {stackVar} {
    upvar 1 $stackVar stk
    return $stk($stk(top))
}
proc pop {stackVar} {
    upvar 1 $stackVar stk
    set val $stk($stk(top))
    unset stk($stk(top))
    incr stk(top) -1
    return $val
}
```

No lists used. But it is a lot more heavyweight than a good list-based implementation needs to be.

Answer (score 0):

There is `struct::stack` in the Tcl standard library. Of course, that package is implemented using lists.

One could also store the stack content in a delimited string and add to / chop off the end of the string.

<s>Or, I think, encode the stack content as integers and use multiplication, division, and module operations to push and pop (the value span needs to be smaller than the smallest item, though).</s> Um, no. Turns out integer multiplication is commutative, who knew?